# Force algorithm under table in a column of 2 column text

Tags: latex

I have an algorithm and a table. I want to display them like this for clarity (algorithm uses some notations defined in the table):

```
----
TABLE
----
ALGO
----
```

I'm using the IEEEtrans class, packages: threeparttable, booktabs, multirow, algorithm2e.

My document:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled, noline, noend, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Example table }
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
              \toprule
              \multirow{2}{*}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test}   \\
                               & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
              \midrule
               Test            & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[\textdagger]    Test
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[!h]
      \caption{Test}
      \For{Test}{ 
        Test
        }
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

I tried

- Put both inside a figure - doesnt work
- Use subcaption package, and put each into a subfigure - I getan error "algocf not allowed inside figure"

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: I have added a short, compilable file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled, noline, noend, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \begin{table}[!h] 
      \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Example table }
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
              \toprule
              \multirow{2}{*}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test}   \\
                               & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
              \midrule
               Test            & Test           & Test            & Test       &  Test          \\
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[\textdagger]    Test
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \medskip
        
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
       \makeatletter
       \@twocolumnfalse
       \makeatother
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Test}
      \For{Test}{ 
        Test
        }
    \end{algorithm}
           \end{minipage}
        \end{table}
    
    \lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]